# What is the difference between ways to declare function type?

Tags: go, type-alias, type-declaration

I can declare a function type in two ways :

```
type opener = func() error

type opener func() error
```

What is the difference between those declarations ? Why would you use one over the other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the language spec, both are [*type declarations*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

`type opener func() error`  is a [*type definition*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions). It introduces a new type named `opener` whose underlying type is `func() error`.

- `opener` and `func() error` are distinct types. They are not interchangeable.
- However, as [Hymns For Disco points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325216/what-is-the-difference-between-ways-to-declare-function-type/68325231?noredirect=1#comment120755212_68325231), because they have the same underlying type (`func() error`), an expression of type `opener` [can be assigned](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to a variable of type `func() error`, and vice versa.
- You can declare methods on `opener`.

In contrast, `type opener = func() error` is an [*alias declaration*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations): `opener` is declared as an alias for the `func() error` type.

- The two types are "synonyms" and perfectly interchangeable.
- You cannot declare methods on `opener` here because `func() error` is not a defined type. In the more general case, you can declare methods on a type alias only if the aliased type is a type defined in the same package as the alias.

---

The [primary motivation](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/18130-type-alias.md) for the addition of type aliases to the language (in [Go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#introduction)) was gradual code repair, i.e. moving types from one package to another. There are a few other niche use cases for type aliases, but you most likely want to use a *type definition* rather than an *alias declaration*.

Comment: In the second case, `opener` and `func() error` are actually interchangeable (at least in the sense that values of each type are assignable to values of the other type. I'm not sure what other meaning of interchangeable would be applicable though). This is because function types like `func() error` are not "defined types", so they pass under the 2nd [assignability rule](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).